# Execute hidden command line?

Tags: c++, cmd

I am using the following piece of code...

```
::_tsystem( _T("taskkill /F /T /IM MSC.exe") );
```

however, a cmd is shown when this code is executed!

How can I use this code without the cmd being shown?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to execute the command hidden, unless it's for malicious purposes.

Comment: then don't use system exec() type calls and talk to the relevant Windows API calls directly instead.

Comment: @JesusRamos, it is not for malicious purposes and rather it is to make those not fear my crappy way of killing my program.

Comment: @JesusRamos That's irrelevant. He didn't say he was using it for malicious purposes, so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: `::_tsystem` - you now have a serious security issue (or rather; quite a few) on your hands. Just don't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `::_tsystem()` function internally uses the CMD.EXE tool to run your command, and CMD.EXE is a console program, so you cannot prevent the console window from showing.

If you want to that you'll have to run the program using the proper Win32 API call: `CreateProcess()`. It is a bit more convoluted, but not too much:

```
STARTUPINFO si;
memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
TCHAR cmd[] = _T("taskkill /F /T /IM MSC.EXE");

BOOL res = CreateProcess(NULL,
      cmd,
      NULL, NULL,
      FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
      NULL, NULL,
      &si, &pi);
if (!res)
    error();
else
{
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    CloseHandle(hThread);
}
```

Note the flag `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` to avoid creating a console window even if the program is a console-type application.

And beware of the `cmd` parameter!. From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The Unicode version of this function, CreateProcessW, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation.

So you must use a local array or characters (TCHAR[]), never a literal string.

Also note that when the function succeeds, the PROCESS_INFORMATION struct returns two open handles, one for the newly created process and another for its main thread. It is your responsibility to close these handles, or they will leak.

Moreover, you can use the `pi.hProcess` to wait for the process to finish:

```
WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. This works .. I have noticed thought, that if I need to wait for the process to finish I have to call `CloseHandle(..)` after `WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);`

Answer (score 3):

have you tried something like:

```
::_tsystem( _T("cmd /Q /C taskkill /F /T /IM MSC.exe") );
```

**EDIT**

Given that nothing seems to be working using system, [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is your best bet. I think the implementation would look something like this:

```
::ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, L"taskkill", L"/F /T /IM MSC.exe", NULL, SW_HIDE);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done the following to kill an external process by executing a hidden command prompt and line.

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInfo;
STARTUPINFO StartupInfo;

LPSTR cmdArgs = "taskkill /F /T /IM MSC.exe";

StartupInfo.cb = sizeof(StartupInfo);
        StartupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
        StartupInfo.hStdInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
        StartupInfo.hStdOutput =  GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        StartupInfo.hStdError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
        StartupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

        CreateProcess(NULL,cmdArgs,NULL,NULL,false,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NO_WINDOW,NULL,NULL,&StartupInfo,&ProcessInfo);
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Nice work! But please see my new answer with a few details that you are missing. Moreover, you do not need that handle stuff, as you are not redirecting input nor output.

Answer (score 0):

I second that you should use CreateProcess -- but you should definitely not use it directly. Why?
Because CreateProcess() is creating a resource 
(the two handles, one for the process and one for the main thread) 
which need to be closed when not needed anymore and after CreateProcess() was successful.
CreateProcess() belongs into the constructor and CloseHandle() (twice) into the destructor.
In case of CreateProcess() fails, you abort the constructor by throwing an exception,
whicb gets passed the return value of GetLastError() and potentially a string explaining that CreateProcess() failed. This exception type should convert the error code into the system error string.

Please leave this C programming philosophy behind you.
Use C++ as such and not as C!

Answer (score 0):

Came to this in search of the same answer but ended up finding my own way within the docs(msdn) 'cause I didn't want to deal with CreateWindow and all that as I like things I can-mostly-remember easier for the next time I have to research it again.

So I've come back here to share another way that works that's much simpler, imo, and achieves exactly what you're looking for; no annoying black box popup commands.

```
System::Diagnostics::Process^ p = gcnew System::Diagnostics::Process();
p->StartInfo->UseShellExecute = false;
p->StartInfo->FileName = "cmd"; //yes, use cmd
p->StartInfo->Arguments = "/c taskkill /f /t /im MSC.exe"; //yes, use /c in the beginning. All the rest after /c is your normal commands you would run
p->StartInfo->CreateNoWindow = true;
p->Start();
```